slope function does not work for the segmented mixed linear model
I want to study the relationship between y and x in a linear mixed model with subjects as a random effect (including both random intercept and slope terms). I fit two models, fit1 and fit2 as follows:
### fit1_linear mixed model
fit1 <- lme(y~x,random =  ~ 1 + x | subjects, data=TT)


### fit2_segmented mixed model with null left slope constraint
fit1_1 <- lme(y~1,random =  ~ 1 + 1 | subjects,data=TT)

fit2 <- segmented(fit1_1,seg.Z = ~x,
               random=list(subjects=pdDiag(~1+DAMAGE+U+G0)),
               psi = 0.40)

I use AIC to compare fit1 and fit2, the second one was better. When I used the slope() function to get the right slope of segmented mixed model, it showed that:

Error in V[final.names, final.names] : subscript out of bounds.

How can I get the right slope of the mixed model?
